# Windows 7 Jenkins installation with admin rights says insufficient privileges to start services

Tags: windows-7, installation, administrator, jenkins

I tried to install Jenkins on Windows 7 home edition and got the following error.

Service 'Jenkins' (Jenkins) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.

I have admin rights for my user account but still not able to install Jenkins.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the setup file and pressing "Run as administrator" before launching. This should run the setup file with escalated privileges and resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd prompt -> net user administrator-> If account active is showing NO -> Then type these command to active - > net user administrator /active:yes

It worked perfectly in my case!

Answer (score 0):

don't close retry and cancel button at this stage,
instead go to services in windows and right click on jenkins service properties and click on logon then choose this account and and pick account in pc(whatever account you are choosing that account should have log on as service- local security option).

now click on retry option in jenkins installation
this will solve the problem